# Progress bar with breaks in angular

Tags: angular, angular11

I am working on angular app and want to have a progress bar as shown in attached image.

[image: progress_bar]  [image: progress_bar2]

I have seen many progress bar online but I am not able to find progress bar of this type. How I can get progress bar of this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine can there're a better way to do it, but you can get it drawing the "separators" then you can make something like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="progress" [style.width.%]="porc"></div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div *ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]" ></div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper
{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}
.wrapper div
{
  height: 1rem;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  margin-top:-1rem;
}
.flex div{
  width:.15rem;
  background: white;
}
.progress{
  background:steelblue;
}
```

If we want to show a gray "items", we can draw

```
<div
  class="wrapper fade">
  <div *ngFor="let color of colors"></div>
</div>
```

And

```
.wrapper.fade
{
  margin-bottom:-1rem;
}
.wrapper.fade div
{
  background:silver
}
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2z1sv3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

**Update**

The idea is create a div that has a width in percent equal to a variable "porc", the `[style.width.%]="porc"`

The "marks" are really a divs with width:.15rem (in the .css are the `.flex div`). You can replace `background: white;` by `background: silver;` to see that really the div are painted.

When we use css-flex, we can indicate items are distributed so that the spacing between any two items (and the space to the edges) is equal using [justify-content:space-evenly](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-justify-content)

In the code I make that the margin-top of the div with class ".flex" was -1rem, the same heigth that the divs-. We can also use margin-bottom:-1rem applied to the progress bar

If we want to create a component the only is that the variable "porc" was an `@Input`

I updated the stackblitz with a component and with another .css that makes the same

**Update 2***

If we can change the color of the progress bar according the "porc", we can use a "getter" of color

```
get color(){
  if (this.porc>80)
     return 'red';
  if (this.porc>60)
     return 'orange';
  if (this.porc>40)
     return 'green';
  return yellow;
}
```

And use

```
<div [style.background]="color" ...>
```

**Update 3**

There're another way to create a progress bar, using [clip-path](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)

Using clip-path, we can do something like

```
<div class="wrapper"
  [style.clip-path]="
    'polygon(0 0, ' + porc + '% 0, ' + porc + '% 100%, 0% 100%)'
  "
>
   <div *ngFor="let color of colors" [style.background-color]="color"></div>
</div>
```

Now we can define an array of colors like

```
colors=["yellow","yellow","yellow","orange","orange","orange","red","red","red"]
```

The .css using css-flex

```
.wrapper
{
  display:flex;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-left:-.125rem;
}
.wrapper div
{
  flex-grow: 1;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:.125rem;
}
```

If we want to see a items silver, we can draw another div

```
<div
  class="wrapper fade">
  <div *ngFor="let color of colors" ></div>
</div>

.wrapper.fade
{
  margin-bottom:-1rem;
}
.wrapper.fade div
{
  background-color:silver;
}
```

And we can see how the "silvers" items are colored when the porc change

Updated in the stackblitz under a component progress-bar-coloured

Comment: is it responsive?

Comment: is it possible if you can explain your code?

Comment: and how can I map it to percentage value?

Comment: @Roma, I updte the answer and the stackblitz (I hope I've explained a bit the code, else ask again)

Comment: I doubt in this suppose the value of proc is 40, so the progress bar is at 40%, and will be with color, how we can show rest 60% blank?

Comment: updated one more image with 80% for reference. progress bar is filled with color till 80% and for rest 20% it is black. Could you please help in this?

Comment: @Roma, you can use a "getter" and [style.background], see updated answer

Comment: but the problem is when progress is suppose 80%, so for 80% in your code progress bar is visible but for rest 20% progress bar is not visible. I want progress bar to be visible for 100% and if progress is 80% then color should be filled till 80% and for rest 20% grey or black color showing emoty area should be there. How can we do that?

Comment: @Roma, In this case we need take another aproach: use clip-path, I just update again the answer and the stackblitz (see in the stackblitz the "progress-bar-colured.component")